# Keeping fixed footer and header from overlapping

Tags: javascript

I finally got my code right and made a fixed header and footer for a template i am working on, and re sizes according to window size just fine. Is there a way to keep my header and footer from touching each other when i resize window. My header is 190px high and my footer is 134px high. I need something like when to position of footer is 190px from top of page to prevent it from going higher

need something like this:

```
if(window_size_height = 325px){
then stop resizing!}
```

or

```
if(footer 325px from top){
then footer_y_position cannot go higher}
```

here is sample to test

http://jsfiddle.net/KYyB7/

edit:

```
$(window).resize(function(){   
if($(window).height() < 435+$('#header').height()){
    $('#footer').css('position','relative');
} else {
    $('#footer').css('position','fixed');
}
});
```

Comment: How can they touch each other? Are you making your window smaller than 324px? You need to have a look at media queries.

Comment: In other words if i go from full screen to windowed, and i adjust size to  make window smaller.  Right now if i do that, my footer goes behind my header. I would like for it to keep my from re sizing if  325 window height

Comment: You want to keep your window from re-sizing below 325 pixels? That is not possible.

Comment: What about just stopping the footer at 325 from going up further, so  then it can just resize

Comment: Yep that is possible. If you use CSS3 media queries. Search SO for mediaqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is either use CSS3 media queries as I mentioned or you can use JavaScript / jQuery.

This is a way to do it in jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){   
    if($(window).height() < 325){
        $('#footer').css('position','relative');
    } else {
        $('#footer').css('position','fixed');
    }
});
```